# Show the changed CRS in the QGIS attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I am using QGIS to read a polygon shapefile with a Dutch CRS (EPSG:28992 to be precise). Now I would like to change the CRS and export the changed CRS to Tableau, so I can build polygon graphs. I know how to export the data to Tableau by copy pasting the attributes table, processing the data further in R and exporting it to Tableau.

I also found how to change the CRS in QGIS into EPSG:4326 by `Project > Project Settings`. After changing the CRS the map changes, showing the correct coordinates. However the attributes table is still showing the original coordinates. Can anyone tell me if there is a way such that the attributes tables shows the changed CRS as well, such that I can export it?

I am a GIS newbie, so bare with me if this is a duplicated question. I could not find the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the coordinates of your source data, you have to `Rightclick -> Save As ...` and write the data to another file on the disk using another CRS for the target.

The attribute table is not changed, you have to use field calculator to add `$x` and `$y` as new table columns with the updated coordinates. This will only work on point data.

Comment: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Adding-coordinates-to-an-attribute-table-td4977019.html